# MYSQL Error Code: 1422. Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that inserts data into the "**contador**" column of the **ATRACCIONES** table, and first checks if that column exists and if not creates it.

But I get the following error that I don't know how to fix:

> Error Code: 1422. Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored
> function or trigger.

```
USE CIRCO;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS atracciones_numAtracc_INSERT;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER atracciones_numAtracc_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON ATRACCION_DIA FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_col varchar(20);

    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    INTO v_col
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'contador' AND TABLE_NAME = 'ATRACCIONES';

    IF (v_col IS NULL) THEN
        ALTER TABLE ATRACCIONES ADD `contador` int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0; 
    END IF;
        
    UPDATE ATRACCIONES
    SET contador = contador + 1
    WHERE nombre = NEW.nombre_atraccion;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Read until full assimilation of the material: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

Comment: Perhaps do the insert in a procedure where you can alter table.(leaving the trigger to do the update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do the update and keep the trigger simple. Don't try to check in the trigger for columns that don't exist.

```
CREATE TRIGGER atracciones_numAtracc_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON ATRACCION_DIA FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE ATRACCIONES
    SET contador = contador + 1
    WHERE nombre = NEW.nombre_atraccion;
END $$
```

Write the trigger with an assumption that the columns you need do exist.

Before you insert data, make sure the tables do contain the needed columns. It is a common practice to apply ALTER TABLE statements to your tables as you deploy a new version of your application. Then you only need to check once.

Checking for the missing column every time you insert a row of data, which could happen millions of times, is an unnecessary and wasteful action.